# How to use Google Maps API V3 to diplay circle with Openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2, google-maps-api

I found bellow code to display Circle by click event with Radius 60.0m.(google maps API v3). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15111403/google-maps-api-v3-change-circle-radius-by-click-event
 I want to display a circle (within a limit of 3000m, 5000m )  and the popup window to appear attribute details of buffer zone. (school name and the school type & etc.,). 
Please help me  to properly place a this JavaScript code into my  HTML page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks. draw a circle with openlayers.(http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/regular-polygons.html)

I'm trying to intersect a user drawn polygon(circle) with a Point WMS Feature Layer. I am using the following code

```
   result = [] testPolygon = vectorTest.features[0].geometry;for (var i=1; i<vectorTest.features.length; i+=1) {
if testPolygon.intersects(vectorTest.features[i].geometry) {
    result.push(vectorTest.features[i]);
} }
```

but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to draw the circle with OpenLayers. But if you want to do it with the GMaps API, you can use the following to get a reference to the GMaps map instance:

```
var googleLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(/* ... */);
var gmap = googleLayer.mapObject;
```